# url in webview doesn't highlight

Tags: android-webview

I have loaded htm file in assets folder to webview.
It contains few links and when I tap it, it opens url accordingly.
The problem is that I want to give highlight effect when tapped on this link.
Currently, nothing happened when click it even orange rectangle is not shown.
Please rescue me.

Comment: how do you click in android? you meant tap? does your css provide this effect?

Comment: a:link, a:visited is define in stylesheet.